# How to make a Makefile call another Makefile rules?

Tags: shell, unix

As the title says:
How can I call a rule in another Makefile from a Makefile?

**For example:**
I have a folder named "folder1" that has a `makefile1` and another folder named "folder2" which has another `makefile2`.
Now I want to call a rule in `makefile1` from make in "folder2".
How can I do that?

Comment: Show some examples please.

Comment: This should be easy like that: rule1: cd ../folder2 && $(MAKE) rule2

Comment: I incorporated your comment's example into your question. Now the question should be clear.