# How can I pass a variable to a rule in a makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, c++14

I have several projects in a directory and I want to write a Makefile to build any subset **or** all of these projects. Each project is in a folder named after itself, which contains a Makefile.

How do I execute these Makefiles?

Here is what I tried:

```
# Define the project names
PROJECT_NAMES := \
    Project_1 \
    Project_2 \
    Project_3

# Define default behaviour
default: all

# Rule to build all projects
all:
    $(foreach project, $(PROJECT_NAMES), $(CURRENT_PROJECT))

# Rule to build single project
.PHONY $(CURRENT_PROJECT)
$(CURRENT_PROJECT):
    $(MAKE) -C $(CURRENT_PROJECT) make
```

I think this question might have gone for something similar, but it was not answered:
[How to make a Makefile call another Makefile rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569376/how-to-make-a-makefile-call-another-makefile-rules)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793058/412080

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing arguments, prerequisites/dependencies should be used. Here is how I solved it:

```
# Define the project names
PROJECT_NAMES := \
    Project_1 \
    Project_2 \
    Project_3

# Define default behaviour
default: all

# Rule to build all projects now depends on building individual projects
all: $(foreach project, $(PROJECT_NAMES), $(project)_build)

# Rule to build a single project
.PHONY: Project_%
Project_%:
    @echo "****** Building $(subst _build,,$@) ******"
    @$(MAKE) -C $(subst _build,,$@) all
```

When called without parameters, all projects are built. Any combination of individual projects can be built by simply passing the project names to the makefile such as:

```
make Project_1 Project_3
```